# Force triggering of moviePlaybackComplete method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

sorry for the question title. Didn't know how to call it.
Heres my issues. I'm loading a video in my iPad app. It is opened in a kind of lightbox.
The Video is played correctly.
Now, when I touch the background the video should close and released just like when the video is finished (moviePlaybackComplete)
And I don't know how to do that. Heres my code so far:

```
    - (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *playButton = (UIButton *) sender; 

    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mymovie" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(playButton.frame.origin.x,
                                                    playButton.frame.origin.y,
                                                    640,
                                                    360)];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}

- (IBAction)hideVideo:(id)sender
{
    if(fadeView.hidden == NO){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishedVideoFading)];
        fadeView.alpha = 0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];  

        [moviePlayerController stop];
        [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [moviePlayerController release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that "lightbox" a view controller? If yes, then when the video finish close the view.

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```